# How to know the type of audio through .rtp file

Tags: php

## There is a .rtp file, how to know what type of audio it is (mp4...).

## Here's what I tried

```
<?php
$fileName = "rtp.rtp";
$file = fopen($fileName, 'rb');
if (!$file) {
  die("无法打开");
}
// 读取RTP文件头部，通常12字节
$rtpHeader = fread($file, 12);
// 提取payload type 字段(占头部第2个字节的低7位)
$payloadType = ord($rtpHeader[1]) & 0x7F;
// 根据payload type 确定音频类型
$audioCodec = getAudioCodecName($payloadType);
echo $audioCodec;
fclose($file);
function getAudioCodecName($payloadType) {
  switch ($payloadType) {
    case 0:
        return "PCMU";
    case 8:
        return "PCMA";
    case 3:
        return "GSM";
    // 添加更多的映射关系
    default:
        return "未知编码类型";
  }
}
```

This method is not very reliable.
I didn't find any other third-party libraries.